# Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Need help with running `bundle` command in a Rails project, I receive the following error:

```
Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
Could not find rack-protection-1.5.5 in any of the sources
```

***gem install rack-protection -v 1.5.5*** works perfectly, the gem gets installed, however when I run *bundle* or *bundle install* again I sill receive the missing gem error. I checked GEM PATHS directories and the gem is indeed in there. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to delete **vendor/cache** directory completelly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when running bundle install:

```sh
 > [ 9/16] RUN bundle install --jobs 2 --retry 3 --local:
#13 1.685 Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
#13 1.692 Could not find racc-1.6.0 in any of the sources
```

The solution for me was to update from bundler 2.2.18 to 2.3.4